# How can I get the row's value start from 1,048,577 to end of the very large excel file?

Tags: c#

I have a very large excel file which I opened with notepad++ count to 1,261,286 rows. How can I have the row's value from 1,048,577 to 1,261,286 of this sheet by C#? I have tried to read it but... please take a look at 2 pictures.

Read by c#
[image: read with c#]

Open with notepad++
[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you can open this in Notepad++ and it looks like a well-formatted text file rather than binary data, it is very likely that you are actually dealing with tab-delimited data.

If that is the case, you can use the fast, efficient and open-source CSV reader

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

I use that in numerous projects and it works like a charm.

You would read all rows, ignoring rows that are not in the range you are interested in.

Code would be along the lines of

```
int lineNr = 1;
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(pathToTheFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(bs), true))
{
    while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
    {
        if (YouCareAboutLine(lineNr))
        {
            DoSomethingWithThisLine();
        }
        lineNr++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely a tab delimited file. The OP is running up the maximum number of rows available in Excel. See: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005199291

Comment: Thanks @aquinas! You're right. How can I deal with maximum number of rows in Excel?

Comment: You can't :). You need to use something like CSV Reader like Eric J is saying. I mean, if you're trying to read an honest to goodness excel file, well, don't worry about it, because there can't be an Excel file saved with more than 1048566 rows. If it's a CSV file on the other hand, use something else to read it.

Comment: You cannot *load* more than the maximum into Excel, but you can use the CsvReader to split the original document into multiple "Excel" (really tab-separated value) documents.  I suspect that using the Excel Interop interface for a document that large will be *extremely slow*.

Comment: Thank you guys! now I understood. May be @EricJ.'s answer is the only way to solve this problem. I'll accepted it at the moment.